# select box click function no longer detected bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using bootstrap select, however, when I add in the `class="selectpicker"` any non-multiple select boxes loses their ability to detect the click functionality.

I have the function:

```
$("select").click(function()
{
    if (this.id.match(/rest/g))
    {
        return;
    }
    name = this.id;
    console.log(name);

    select_id = name.replace("_free", "");
    radio = select_id + '_radio';
    //$('input:radio[name='+radio+']:checked').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
    document.getElementById(select_id + "_radio3").checked = true;
}
```

What this does is determine which select was clicked on, which then changes the checked radio button. However, after adding in selectpicker, only the ones with `multiple` still change the radio button.

Any idea how to get around this?

https://jsfiddle.net/34ksL2h5/3/

(remove the `class="selectpicker"` and you'll see the issue)

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Comment: Can you add html code also?

Comment: @HermLuna Added

Comment: It is because selectbox is changed by bootstrap to button.

Comment: Your HTML looks pretty messed up `<div>
  <input id="select1_radio" type="radio" name="radio1">
  <select id="select1">
    <option>some option</option>
    <option>some option</option>
    <option>some option</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="select2_radio" type="radio" name="radio1">
  <select id="select2">
    <option>some option</option>
    <option>some option</option>
    <option>some option</option>
  </select>
</div>`

Comment: I also update your JS to `$("select").click(function()
{

    name = $(this).id;
    document.getElementById(name + "_radio").checked = true;
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
  <input id="select1_radio" type="radio" name="radio1">
  <select id="select1" class="selectpicker">
    <option>some option 1</option>
    <option>some option 2</option>
    <option>some option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="select2_radio" type="radio" name="radio1">
  <select id="select2" class="selectpicker">
    <option>some option 1</option>
    <option>some option 2</option>
    <option>some option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

script. Sorry it's native JS because I don't know how to use jQuery. Hope someone translate it for you.

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('.bootstrap-select');

[].forEach.call(sel, function(elem){
    elem.onclick = function(){
    this.previousElementSibling.checked = true;
  }
});

// $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/34ksL2h5/10/

The trigger was the .bootstrap-select. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I was going to do something with the `div` as well, but if it works, I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Herma Luna's I decided to go find the div instead, with class `boostrap-select`

So using the code below I can get the id.

```
$('div.bootstrap-select').on('click', function(){       
    console.log($(this).find("select").attr("id"));
});
```